# tinc - TCP Cipher method

Tags: vpn, encryption, tinc

In tinc 1.0.x there is `Cipher` param which allows to set encryption for UDP packets. For TCP packets encryption method is not allowed to be changed
http://www.tinc-vpn.org/pipermail/tinc-devel/2005-July/000256.html. What method is used for TCP encryption?

Answer (score 0):

It uses Blowfish OFB as in this line in `net_setup.c`

```
myself->connection->outcipher = EVP_bf_ofb();
```

I dunno why author can not add this param to `tinc.conf`.